# What is a good question about Game industry careers?

Tags: discussion, questions

I saw this question
' [Is this really a good question?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/895/is-this-really-a-good-question) '
asking about a game development career related question. The conclusion was the question asked about should be closed. The reasoning was not very objective in my humble opinion. The flaw in the question was supposedly that it was too broad.

Then I saw this question: ' [Are questions about the game industry welcome here?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/874/are-questions-about-the-game-industry-welcome-here) 'and thought it was not a terrible question if for some reason that figure was needed.
There are ways to scan the web and get a rough guesstimate of how many game companies and game creators exist.

My question is, since both these questions seem alright to me and they're not, perhaps the faq should be more specific about which Game Industry related questions are good and which do not fit the site. Also if you could share an example of a good question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then I saw this question: ' Are questions about the game industry
>   welcome here? 'and thought it was not a terrible question if for some
>   reason that figure was needed. There are ways to scan the web and get
>   a rough guesstimate of how many game companies and game creators
>   exist.

Speaking only for myself, I'm not here to invent trivia.  Even if "scanning the web and getting a rough guesstimate" is involved.

I'm just not.

Nope, no interest in doing that at all.

Now, I don't want to speak for anyone else, but I suspect that most of us who have real jobs and/or expertise in the field aren't interested in spending our limited spare time playing Trivial Pursuit with everyone who can manage to cobble together enough vowels to construct a two-sentence, context-free question which isn't in any obvious or explicitly-stated way related to actually making games.

The difference between a good question and a bad question is pretty obvious, it seems to me.

Comment: So which questions about the Game Industry are related to making games?